# Non fatally handling error in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, error-handling, cryptography

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637618/converting-rsa-keys-to-json-in-perl/35644502#35644502) it was recommended that I use the module [`Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA`](http://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA) to export and send RSA keys. However, I have found that this module seems to have no way of non-fatally handling errors and as a result by simply sending a malformed string (i.e. not an RSA key) the server program will crash when it tries to create a new object using it with the message:

> unrecognized key format at server.pl line 46

Line 46 contains the code

```
$clients{$cur_client}->{pub_key}    = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($message) or do {
            server_log "Bad key exchange, dropping user $address:$port..."; 
            delete $clients{$cur_client};
            next;
        }; # Key exchange
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT: [Here is a link to the full code on Github](https://github.com/Alex-Ferguson/perl_chat_server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the BLOCK form of [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to prevent the program from dying when an exception is raised. Unfortunately a bare use of `eval` is fraught with awkward corner cases and it is best to use the [`Try::Tiny`](http://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny) module which handles these for you

To achieve the purpose of your code in your question, you would write something like this. Clearly you will have to supply useful data for the variables

**It's important to note** that `try` and `catch` are *subroutines*. That means you need a semicolon after `catch`, and you can't `next` within `catch` because you can't do that from within a subroutine. You have to leave some sort of state set so that the subsequent code can do anything necessary there, and in this case I just check whether `$clients{$cur_client}` still exists—it will have been deleted by the `catch` routine if there was a problem

It's also worth explaining that the `die` string is available in `$_` inside the `catch` routine, so you can check the reason for the failure. In this case the `catch` is expecting to handle only `unrecognized key format` errors, so the code checks that that is indeed the reason for the failure. If not then it issues another `die $_` to reflect that an unhandled error has occurred

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use Try::Tiny;

my %clients = ( aa => {} );
my $message = 'xxx';
my ($address, $port) = qw/ 127.0.0.1 80 /;

for my $cur_client ( keys %clients ) {

    try {
        $clients{$cur_client}{pub_key} = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($message);
    }
    catch {
        if ( /unrecognized key format/ ) {
            server_log("Bad key exchange, dropping user $address:$port...");
            delete $clients{$cur_client};
        }
        else {
            die $!;
        }
    };

    next unless exists $clients{$cur_client};

    # More handling of $cur_client in the case that
    # the call to new_public_key succeeds
}

sub server_log {
    print "Logging: $_[0]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but I thought I'd add it so people are aware that you don't need a module to catch errors in Perl, it's built in already. Here's some code to demo Perls inbuilt exception handling...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $a = 100;
my $res = 0;  
eval {
  $res = $a/0;
};
if($@) {
  print("I just caught a divide by zero here... $@\n");
}
```

Heres another example...

```
eval {
  die "please die\n";;
}; 
if($@) {
  print("No, you cannot die just yet... $@\n");
}
```

I've used this idiom for years and it's worked like a charm.

Comment: The accepted answer first mentions `eval`, prior to suggesting that `Try::Tiny` is preferable because `eval` has numerous traps you can fall into and `Try::Tiny` avoids them. For example, your error-handling code will fail to detect that an error occurred if `$@` has a non-true value.  https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny#might-not-be-a-true-value